# Allocating data for the priority_queue on heap

Tags: c++, heap, priority-queue

I'm using C++ priority_queue data structure to store large amount of data on it. However, I always get segmentation fault, probably due to stack overflow error. My priority_queue definition is:

```
typedef struct cell {
    int x;
    int y;
    float value;
}*cell_p;

struct cell_comparator {
    bool operator()(cell_p arg1, cell_p arg2) {
        return arg1->value > arg2->value;
    }
};

priority_queue<cell_p, vector<cell_p>, cell_comparator>* open;
```

and in the main function:

```
open = new priority_queue<cell_p, vector<cell_p>, cell_comparator>();

int x, y;

for (x = 0; x < nXSize; x++) {
    for (y = 0; x < nYSize; y++) {
        int index = (y * nXSize) + x;
        cell_p c = (cell_p) malloc(sizeof(cell));
        c->x = x;
        c->y = y;
        c->value = input_buffer[index];
        open->push(c);
    }
}
```

As a container class, I used vector, but seems like it stores the data on stack, rather than on the heap. How can I tell priority_queue to store data on the heap?

Comment: `std::vector` stores data on heap

Comment: I can assure you that the error is your fault and your fault alone. Though we probably need to see more code (http://sscce.org/) to pinpoint where exactly you went wrong. `std::vector` does not allocate on the stack. Even if it could, in your code the vectors are heap-allocated along with the priority queue.

Comment: That you are mixing `malloc()` with `operator new` in a C++ environment is indicative of a larger problem in itself, and I can assure you that problem is *not* with `std::vector<>`.

Comment: is the typo (**x**) `for (int y = 0; x < nYSize; y++) {` in your code also ?

Comment: As an example of how to do what it seems you're trying without abusing either `operator new` or `malloc()`, [See it live](http://ideone.com/T80bvx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I always get segmentation fault, probably due to stack overflow error.

Your analysis is very likely incorrect. There is very little reason to think there's a stack overflow anywhere in the code you show.

> How can I tell priority_queue to store data on the heap?

It already does.

A good way to tackle the problem is by looking at the stack trace at the point you get the segfault (and including the stack trace in your question).

If that doesn't help, come up with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and post that.

Comment: Ok, I see my stupid bug, it has nothing to do with my priority_queue definition but the code causing infinite loop error here:

    for (y = 0; x < nYSize; y++) {

Thanks all!